# How to return the value of the array in this code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm newbie here., I want to get the array value that I set in an array. 
I have this simple code here. Hope someone could help me..What is the correct way to set this one?

```
<?php
include('datacon.php');
//$id = $_GET['id'];

$list = mysql_query("SELECT PatientID,Fname,Mname,Lname 
         FROM tbl_PatientInfo WHERE PatientID = '1' ");

$result = array();
foreach( mysql_fetch_array($list) as $row){
$result[] = array(

'id' => $row['PatientID'],
'fname' => $row['Fname'],
'mname' => $row['Mname'],
'lname' => $row['Lname']

    );
 }

 echo json_encode($result);

 ?>
```

When i try this code. It said an error:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'PatientID' on line 15

Comment: Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: @PrasanthBendra The code is correct.

Comment: I think it should be `mysql_fetch_array($list, MYSQL_ASSOC)`  - and then you should think about migrating to mysqli (mysql improved)

Comment: The default for `mysql_fetch_array()` is `MYSQL_BOTH`, so it should work.

Comment: @Barmar, YogeshSuthar : Thanks for that information

Comment: try looking @ the mysql_fetch_array() return value, eg. `print_r($row);` just before `$result[]=...`. Also, try to check the return value of mysql_query() against FALSE (you may have an error in your query).

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)){

Comment: Thank you all for information and for quick response! Thanks @Barmar. Got it right!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
foreach( mysql_fetch_array($list) as $row){
```

This is retrieving just one row, and then iterating over the columns in that row. The columns are just strings, not arrays, which is why you get illegal string offset errors.

You want to retrieve each row, you do that with:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an associative array that's why it is invalid to use:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($list) as $row
```

rather than

```
mysql_fetch_array($list) as $row
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` as don't need numeric indexes in your output, so `mysql_fetch_array` is a bit of an overhead.

```
$result = array();
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $list ) ) !== false ) {
  $result[] = array(
    'id' => $row['PatientID'],
    'fname' => $row['Fname'],
    'mname' => $row['Mname'],
    'lname' => $row['Lname']
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch_array() : $row[0], $row[1], etc...

fetch_assoc() : $row['PatientID'], $row['Fname'], etc...

fetch_object() : $row->PatientID, $row->Fname, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('datacon.php');
//$id = $_GET['id'];

$list = mysql_query("SELECT PatientID,Fname,Mname,Lname 
         FROM tbl_PatientInfo WHERE PatientID = '1' ");

$result = array();
$i=0;
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($list)){


$result[$i]['id'] = $row['PatientID'];
$result[$i]['fname'] = $row['Fname'];
$result[$i]['mname'] = $row['Mname'];
$result[$i]['lname'] = $row['Lname'];

    $i++;
 }

 echo json_encode($result);

 ?>
```